# Cron Error :(cd) ERROR (getpwnam() failed - user unknown)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, cron, sudo

I have a simple bash script and it works fine when I execute it directly (`bash testfile.sh`). But when I use it in crontab, it is not working..

```
*/10 * * * * cd /var/trafficviewer/script; ./testfile.sh
```

I made the `chmod +x testfile.sh` as well.In error log, I could found below error..

```
Jul 12 16:45:01 XX crond[1439]: (cd) ERROR (getpwnam() failed - user unknown)
```

Can someone help me on this error?

Note: I dont have root access for this server. I installed these crons by using sudo commands.

Comment: Is there a user named `cd` on your system?

Comment: @stark no.. I used that to run the script... svradmin is a user

Comment: then why are you putting cd where the user name goes?

Comment: @stark I have used this same command for one of my some servers. Thats why..

Comment: */10 * * * * svradmin /var/trafficviewer/script; ./testfile.sh will resolve the issue?

Comment: I don't even know what file you are editing or what users are on your system. I just read the error you were getting. It was pretty clear.

Comment: @kevinnls  Only if the script doesn't use any relative paths.

Comment: as for what @stark said about username. it depends on whether you ran `sudo crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -u svradmin -e`. i think you meant to use the latter :)

Comment: @stark. touché. deleted my other comment to avoid confusion, thank you for catching that